# Describe a back/middle office job

Tags: phrases

I'd like to know any better ways to casually describe a back/middle office job responsibility when briefly introducing myself. The situation is when you just state your position in short to someone (for 10-15 sec.) and you don't need to explain what you do in detail at that time.

I often say like "I'm at a middle-office position. My job is mainly to support the front office team."
But, I know it sounds immature.

The actual job description is very near to the one in the link below. I'd like to know the natural and elegant way to describe those in short. 
https://www.greatsampleresume.com/job-responsibilities/middle-office-analyst-responsibilities/?amp

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is the "Eleanor Oliphant" answer "I work in an office". In the novel, she uses this answer to shut down conversation. People are rarely interested in office work so are happy to accept that. You don't even need to say front/middle/back office.

I see nothing wrong with "I support the front office team." You might give more details by naming the industry sector, or company name (if it is famous), and picking a generic task (like "analysis" or "monitoring")

> I have a middle office role in an insurance company. I mostly do analysis and support the front office team.